# How to search word by word in android

Tags: java, android, string, search

How to search a word in a string?

For example

```
String text = "Samsung Galaxy S Two";
```

If I use `text.contains("???");`

It will get any related alphabets even it is not a proper word such as "axy" from "Galaxy".

Any suggestion or solution?

Comment: Take a look at this post http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html this might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

String text = "Samsung Galaxy S Two";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text);

    //("---- Split by space ------");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        tokens.add(st.nextElement().toString());
    }

    String search = "axy";
    for(int i=0;i<tokens.size();i++)
    {
        if(tokens.get(i).contains(search))
        {
            System.out.println("Word is "+tokens.get(i));
            break;//=====> Remove Break if you want to continue searching all the words which contains `axy`
        }
    }

output====>Galaxy
```

Answer (score 1):

For most simple usage, you can use a StringTokenizer
Look at this link.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

For using Regular expressions, Look at Patterns in android.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

use `indexOf`:

```
int i= string.indexOf('1');
```

or `substring`:

```
String s=string.substring("koko",0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String string = "madam, i am Adam";
```

// Characters

```
// First occurrence of a c
int index = string.indexOf('a');    // 1

// Last occurrence
index = string.lastIndexOf('a');    // 14

// Not found
index = string.lastIndexOf('z');    // -1
```

// Substrings

```
// First occurrence
index = string.indexOf("dam");      // 2

// Last occurrence
index = string.lastIndexOf("dam");  // 13

// Not found
index = string.lastIndexOf("z");    // -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I am writing here so that the next person who needs help can be helped.

You can use **matches**.

```
String str = "Hello, this is a trial text";
str1 = str.toLowerCase();
if(str1.matches(".*trial.*")) //this will search for the word "trial" in str1
{
    //Your Code
}
```